# B2C custom html pages loading animation on button click

Tags: javascript, html, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I use Azure AD B2C custom policies with custom html pages (from Microsoft templates "unified.html" and "selfAsserted.html"). I would like to have a "loading" animation on the "Next" button click. Because sometimes there's a lot going on in the policy and it takes up to 10 seconds, leaving the user with the impression that nothing works. At least I should disable the page or something just to show the user there's a process running. Is there any way to hook into the button click event in Javascript?

In Chrome we can see the icon in the tab and on the bottom left a message saying "Waiting for xxxx", but the lambda user won't even notice that and will try clicking the button over and over like crazy.

Answer (score 2):

For Unified page, you could use a little bit of JavaScript to get what you need. There is a div which is displayed when you click sign in button and is hidden again once it's done.

```js
// Unified page has a built in div with class working which is displayed waiting for sign in call to get completed. You could add styles to this class to show a loader.
const targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('working')[0];
// Sign in button in unified page.
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');

if(targetNode && nextBtn) {
    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["style"] };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {

        // Add a loader class or anything you'd like to do. 
        if (targetNode.style.display == "block") {
            nextBtn.classList.add('loader');
            nextBtn.innerHTML = "Loading...";
        } else {
            nextBtn.classList.remove('loader');
            nextBtn.innerHTML = "Sign In";
        }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sabique for your answer, I'll test it and flag it as answered afterward